# Deploy Android apps via Microsoft Intune from alternative sources

Tags: applications, installation, f-droid, alternative-markets, microsoft-intune

Has anyone experience or knowledge of whether it is possible to deploy Android apps via Microsoft Intune when the source of apps is e.g. the F-Droid app store?

I am considering setting up fully managed Android devices at work, and I am also quite fond of the idea of using open-source apps.
However, installing F-Droid and giving the users the privileges to install apps somehow defeats the purpose and premise of the devices being fully managed.

Comment: Have you tried this for providing non Play Store apps via Intune?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/lob-apps-android

Comment: @Robert, not yet. I guess the lack of alternative methods means that there's not integration for alternative app stores.